# Getting the same output for Stateless and stateful session bean

Tags: ejb, ejb-2.x

Here is the sample code i tried

```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>  
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">  
<html>  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">  
<title>Sample1</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
<form action="ActionServlet" method="post">  
<h1>This is inside sample1</h1>  
<input type="submit">  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

posted Monday, November 19, 2012 10:58:11 PM private message
Quote
Here is the sample code that i tried

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>  
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">  
<html>  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">  
<title>Sample1</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
<form action="ActionServlet" method="post">  
<h1>This is inside sample1</h1>  
<input type="submit">  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

on Clicking submit, control navigates to servlet named ActionServlet

```
 public class ActionServlet extends HttpServlet {  
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;  

    /** 
     * Default constructor.  
     */  
    public ActionServlet() {  
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub  
    }  

    /** 
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
     */  
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        doPost(request, response);  
    }  

    /** 
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
     */  
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        System.out.println("This is inside doPost method for action servlet");  

        System.out.println("Before calling EJB for action servlet");  
        try{  
            Context ic = new InitialContext();  

            //first instance creation  
            StateFulServiceHome home=(StateFulServiceHome)ic.lookup("Stateful1234");  
            StateFulService sample=(StateFulService)home.create();  
            sample.setName("Hello1223");  
            sample.getName();  
            //second instance creation  
            Context ic1 = new InitialContext();  
            StateFulServiceHome home1=(StateFulServiceHome)ic1.lookup("Stateful1234");  
            StateFulService sample1=(StateFulService)home1.create();  
            sample1.getName();  
        }catch (Exception e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
        System.out.println("After calling EJB in action servlet1");  
        request.getRequestDispatcher("Sample2.jsp").forward(request,response);  

    }  

}
```

ActionServlet calls business method on a bean named stateful session bean

```
public class StateFulBean implements SessionBean{  
    String name;  
    public void setName(String name)throws RemoteException{  
        this.name =name;  
    }  
    private SessionContext context;  
    public void ejbActivate() throws EJBException, RemoteException {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        System.out.println("*********This is inside ejbActivate method***********");  

    }  

    public void ejbPassivate() throws EJBException, RemoteException {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        System.out.println("*********This is inside ejbpassivate method***********");  

    }  

    public void ejbRemove() throws EJBException, RemoteException {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        System.out.println("*********This is inside Ejb remove method***********");  

    }  
    public void ejbCreate() throws EJBException,RemoteException{  
        System.out.println("*********This is inside create method***********");  
    }  
    public void setSessionContext(SessionContext ctx) throws EJBException,  
            RemoteException {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        context=ctx;  
        System.out.println("*********This is for set session context***********");  
    }  
    public void getName()throws RemoteException{  
        System.out.println("***********This is for start of getting business method*****");  
        System.out.println("The name obtained is"+this.name);  
        System.out.println("***********This is for end of getting business method*****");  
    }  

} 

    public interface StateFulService extends EJBObject {  
    public void getName()throws RemoteException;  
    public void setName(String name)throws RemoteException;  
} 



  public interface StateFulServiceHome extends EJBHome {  
    public StateFulService create() throws RemoteException,CreateException;  
}
```

and finally my ejb-jar.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE ejb-jar PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Enterprise JavaBeans 2.0//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/ejb-jar_2_0.dtd">  
<ejb-jar>  
 <enterprise-beans>  
   <session>  
      <ejb-name>Stateful1234</ejb-name>  
      <home>StateFulServiceHome</home>  
      <remote>StateFulService</remote>  
      <ejb-class>StateFulBean</ejb-class>  
      <session-type>Stateful</session-type>  
      <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>  
   </session>  
</enterprise-beans>  
</ejb-jar>
```

I am getting the same output for stateful and stateless session bean, My assumption is when my bean is defined as stateful, I should get the name during lookup of bean for the second time.

Let me know if I am wrong somewhere.

-Shyam

Answer (score 0):

> My assumption is when my bean is defined as stateful, I should get the name during lookup of bean for the second time.

That's not how stateful session beans work. When you use a stateful session bean, you can store the proxy to the bean "somewhere" i.e. so that the container will passivate it when you do not invoke methods on it for a certain period. The container would "remember" the client (the servlet in your case), should a subsequent request be made through the proxy at any time before the bean is destroyed. In other words, subsequent invocations will remember the conversational state, and hence the stateful nature of the session bean. You can store state in the session bean, even across HTTP requests (hence, the reason for storing the reference to the proxy).

Note that this has very little to do with lookups. In your code:

```
//first instance creation  
StateFulServiceHome home=(StateFulServiceHome)ic.lookup("Stateful1234");  
StateFulService sample=(StateFulService)home.create();  
sample.setName("Hello1223");  
sample.getName();  
//second instance creation  
Context ic1 = new InitialContext();  
StateFulServiceHome home1=(StateFulServiceHome)ic1.lookup("Stateful1234");  
StateFulService sample1=(StateFulService)home1.create();  
sample1.getName();
```

you've created two instances of the session bean and you have two proxies to them. The second bean is obviously not going to know of the state stored in the first.

To consider stateless session beans, then you'll need to remember that it is a bit pointless to store references to their proxies, especially in a `HttpSession` object. This is primarily because state stored within the bean is valid only for the duration of the method invocation. The EJB container manages a pool of stateless session beans, and each invocation may involve a different unused instance in the pool.

PS - Is there any reason why you're learning EJB 2.x now ? Not only is it old, parts of it are no longer required in Java EE 6 apps, and some portions (entity beans) are being pruned in Java EE 7.